# Excel data validation multiple columns drop down

Tags: excel

In excel when I use data validation I can only make a single column to add it drop down.
I want to **add specific rang in a cell drop down like B4 to G15. On click on specific cell that rang appears as like as drop down list.** *Any one please helps me.*

Answer (score 0):

U can use this formula in order to transfer multicolumn range to single column, myRange is named range for B4:G15 and put this formula into N2 and fill down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(myRange,ROWS($N$2:N2)-INT((ROWS($N$2:N2)-1)/ROWS($B$4:$G$15))*ROWS($B$4:$G$15),INT(((ROWS($N$2:N2)-1)/ROWS($B$4:$G$15)+1))),"")
```

Here is example file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzFv0oeets6ucnBCcmg0NGM2bTQ

Comment: Yes. By using Data validation we can deal with only one column.

Comment: If you want,  you can create single column items with this formula. Just give a name "myRange" to your B4:G15 range and put this formula into cell N2 and fill down,  then choose this column for data validation:
=IFERROR(INDEX(myRange,ROWS($N$2:N2)-INT((ROWS($N$2:N2)-1)/ROWS(myRange))*ROWS(myRange),INT((ROWS($N$2:N2)-1)/ROWS(myRange)+1)),"")

Comment: Sorry, Named ranges don't work inside ROWS() formula, I updated my answer.

Comment: did you try my sample file?